# Clearly Displaying Factor Levels in a Regression Table

Tags: r, regression, report

I submitted the following table for peer review in a manuscript. The reviewer comments showed that the table confused them. In our study we have a pre- and post-score that we measured as DVs. Our predictors included 2 dummy variables, a "Theme" factor variable that included 5 levels, GEF, XYZ, ABC, DEF, and MNO. We had two continuous variables, variable 1 and 2, at level one. And, we had two continuous variables, variable 3 and 4, at level two.

The reviewers complained that our regression table mysteriously dropped a theme. This is because the way R reports factors is by using one theme as a reference level and then including the other levels in the regression output. That is what I reflected in the table with a note that says that "Theme GEF is the reference theme."

I'm looking for suggestions on how to better format this table so future reviewers will understand that there is a reference theme and that is why it doesn't show up in the table. I am considering converting the 5 themes into separate dummy variables, as that would cause them to all show up in the table. But, that is more work and defeats the purpose of having factors. Any suggestions are appreciated.

(I've simplified the variable names so that this question doesn't rely on knowledge of our domain.)

[image]

Comment: Not an R question really. It's a journal question. The journal at hand must have publication guidelines which specifies what a chart should look like. It's possible there's a tag on stack or crossvalidated where this is an appropriate question, but I wouldn't know which one. Alternatively, look at other articles the journal has published.

Comment: Thanks--yeah this is a hard to classify. I put R because the table is based on the way R formats regression results that contain factors. I'll continue looking for some other example tables I might emulate.